# How do you represent log base 100 (n) with big O, theta, omega

Tags: big-o

I'm having trouble finding out if log base 100 (n) in O(log(n)), Omega(log(n)), or Theta(log(n)).

I think it's in O(log(n)) and only O(log(n)) because at most the function will have an upper asymptotic bound at log(n) but because the rate of change of log base 100 n is smaller than log(n), it can't have a lower bound at log(n).

I'm new to big O, Omega, Theta though and am curious if my answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotic notations like big O, big Omega, etc are set notation.

`Ω(g(n))` is the set of all functions in the form `f(n)` whose order of growth is **greater than or equal to** that of `g(n)`.

`Θ(g(n))` is the set of all functions in the form `f(n)` whose order of growth is **equal to** that of `g(n)`.

`O(g(n))` is the set of all functions in the form `f(n)` whose order of growth is **less than or equal to** that of `g(n)`.

Like you pointed out below, because the functions differ by only a constant, the function `log100(n)` is a member of al three sets: `O(log(n))`, `Θ(log(n))` and `Ω(log(n))`.

I've recently written [an article on asymptotic notation](https://stevethescholar.com/asymptotic-notation/) that elaborates on this in more detail.

Comment: Ah, you’re right. If the difference is just a constant then they are the same order of growth and it would then be a member of all three sets. Sorry for the bad information. I’ve corrected my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The Big-O is just to compare the complexity of the programs which means how fast are they growing when the inputs are increasing and not the exact time which is spend to do the action.

So to make it simple mostly a few known equations are used and different base for log is not actually being used in the big-O notations and all are just equivalent of long n.

[image: Big-O Complexity Chart]

Regarding your comment, I would like to make it more clear:

O, Omega and Theta are used in the same way but each of them has different meaning:

- big-O is used to show the upper bound of the growth
- Omega is used to show the lower bound of the growth
- Theta is the exact complexity

IMHO, in any of the big-O equations you better not to use more complex equations (you might just stick to the ones in the above graph.)
However you still might use other more precise equations (like 3^n, n^3, ...) but it can be sometimes misleading! So better to keep it as simple as possible.

Regarding the log100(n) is also similar maybe you don't need to precisely mention that and using the log(n) would be just enough?

I would like to emphasize once again that here we don't want to get an exact formula for our algorithm. We only want to show how it grows when the inputs are growing and compare with the other algorithms in that sense. Otherwise you would better use different methods like bench-marking.